# I need my values to not repeat their names in their categories

Tags: python, rows

[image: Python Data with Row Names Repeating]

I am not sure how to fix this. This is the code I want, but I do not want it to continuously repeat the names of the rows in the output.

Comment: Hi there, please post your code formatted as code. Images of code are not accepted on StackOverflow

Comment: `pd.read_csv` produces a DataFrame.  You do not need ANY of those `d = pd.DataFrame(df)` lines.

Comment: @NickBailey - Unfortunately, I cannot delete nor edit the question. The site is also not allowing me to create a new question, so we're stuck with this.

Comment: @TimRoberts - Thank you for the helpful comment, but unfortunately, that still does not answer my main question.

Comment: Your `sum` is producing two rows.  You only want to print the second row.  Without seeing your csv we can't be sure, but `...sum()['Cost']` or `...sum().loc["Cost"]` looks like the right answer to me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a few changes to your code.
Firstly, to answer your question, you can remove the multiple occurences of the words by using:

```
select_merch = d.loc[df['Category] == 'Merchandise'].sum()['Cost]
```

This will make sure to select only the sum of the `Cost` column for a particular dataframe. Also this code is very redundant and confusing. What you can do is also create a list and iterate over it for each category.

`list(df['Category'].unique())` will give you a list of all the unqiue categories. Store it in a list and then iterate over it. Plus, you don't need to do a d=pd.Dataframe(df) everytime, you can use df itself as well.